# Laravel filter products by category name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I use Bagisto E-Commerce platform (build laravel + vue) and I have created package where I want list categories and filter products by category name.

I don't know how exactly filter products by one view and in bagisto they list products by category page e.g. example.com/category-name

I try to use this [example](https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-6-filter-data-using-vue-js), but can't get it working, because I don't know where I get class "Products" and function AllProducts.

Can someone guide me in the right direction of how I could get this to work correctly?

This is what I'm trying to do: https://codepen.io/mrsingleton/pen/aYVBvV

My code in products view:

```
$categories = [];

foreach (app('Webkul\Category\Repositories\CategoryRepository')->getVisibleCategoryTree(core()->getCurrentChannel()->root_category_id) as $category) {

array_push($categories, $category);

 }
            
 ?>

    @if (count($categories))

        <div class="list-container" style="text-align:center;margin-top: 50px;">
           <ul class="list-group">

             @foreach ($categories as $key => $category)
                 
                  <li> {{ $category->name }} </li>
             
             @endforeach
             
           </ul> 
        </div>

    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bagisto, Laravel translatable has been used. Thats why you need to use the different approaach to achieve this. As directly by `name`, you won't be able to achive because the rest columns are on different tables i.e. `category_translations`.

If you check the `Categories` model in namespace i.e. `Webkul\Category\Models\Category`, it is already linked to the `Product` model. So you can directly chain it to fetch all associated products.

```php
/* fetch category by name */
$categoryName = 'Category 1';

$category = Category::whereHas(
    'translations',
    function ($query) use ($categoryName) {
        $query->where('name', $categoryName);
    }
)->first();

$relatedProducts = $category->products;

/* rest is your operations */
```